# Wordpress, can't get advanced custom fields plugin to work

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I tried following the instruction s but can't get the plugin to work, the fields show in admin and i upload images with them but when I publish and view the post no images show. Do I need to add something to template files for this to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from the producer's [page](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) they state that for images/files **their API** returns a URL.

That might mean that the plug-in is not integrated with the native file handling functions. And you might need to use their template tags like `<img src="<?php the_field('name') ?>" />`.

```
file: public_html/wp-content/themes/theme_name/category.php
```

somewhere after this

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <img src="<?php the_field('name') ?>" />
        ...
```

Comment: I am extremely new to php, I had read the docs but didn't quite get it so I was hoping someone might be able to walk through where I need to put these tags?

Comment: Thank you I had to put the code into loop single. I ve got that working just need to figure out how to make it only upload thumnails now thanks again

Comment: You can't upload only thumbnails unless they use SWFUpload as an input widget, which i haven't seen in the code. You can however upload the full size image and show the thumbnailed image.

Comment: I have it working in single post view. Problem is my category.php does have the code you have pictured above, my theme is a child of the twenty ten theme if this helps

Comment: ignore that last question I have fixed it thank you for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to add:

```
<?php the_field('field_name'); ?>
```

Check ACF docs: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/code-examples/

Comment: so if I wanted to add them to every post would it go in single.php or something?